# Swift 5: getting several values out of JSON with array root object

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, parsing

I (a complete rookie) am currently trying to create my first iOS app - a currency table/converter for the currency of my country, Ukrainian Hryvna. I have created a TableView that I am going to fill with data from JSON file from the following link:
[Tap here](https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json)

The file itself has Array root. Like that:

```
 [
{ 
"r030":36,"txt":"Австралійський долар","rate":21.334,"cc":"AUD","exchangedate":"23.12.2020"
 }
,{ 
"r030":124,"txt":"Канадський долар","rate":21.9334,"cc":"CAD","exchangedate":"23.12.2020"
 }
,{ 
"r030":156,"txt":"Юань Женьміньбі","rate":4.3192,"cc":"CNY","exchangedate":"23.12.2020"
 }
,{ 
"r030":191,"txt":"Куна","rate":4.5833,"cc":"HRK","exchangedate":"23.12.2020"
 }]
```

I want to get a create a Dictionary out of this file using just two values: [cc: rate] and then fill my TableView with this data. I don't care for other values.

Something like that:

```
["AUD": 21.334, "CAD": 21.9334]
```

Should I use some other data type to store this data? A Struct representing a currency and then make an Array of currency Structs, perhaps?

How do I get this file from that URL and make such a Dictionary/Struct array/...?

Thank you so much in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a struct

```
struct Currency : Decodable {
    let name : String
    let rate : Double

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case name = "cc", rate }
}
```

Then load the data with `URLSession` and decode the JSON array to `[Currency]` with `JSONDecoder` (there are zillions of examples of both).

Comment: Thank you, sir! Makes perfect sense. But could you please elaborate the purpose of that private enum line. What do we need it for?

Comment: It's for *translating*  the key `cc` to `name` and to omit all other keys but `rate`.